# How to send arbitrary strings to STDERR via FastCGI wiith PHP?

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi, stderr

I would like my message to appear directly in my NginX error log, like

```
2020/06/04 16:23:00 [error] 9057#9057: *26 FastCGI sent in stderr: "MESSAGE" while reading response header from upstream, client: 151.24.155.27, server: "fqdn", request: "GET /page.php HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "hostname"
```

I know that PHP can write to STDERR when executed via CLI, but I'm referring to a webpage.

Comment: Could you not use the error_log function? Ex: `error_log("This is my message", 0);`

Comment: @WayneWhitty yes, I just tried it and it works, you can post an answer like mine so I can select yours.

Comment: You can select your own answer!

Comment: My answer was the latest one, so i delete it to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RTFM I guess](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php).

This:

```php
<?php error_log("MESSAGE", 0);?>
```

ends up like this:

```
2020/06/04 16:23:00 [error] 9057#9057: *26 FastCGI sent in stderr: "MESSAGE" while reading response header from upstream, client: 151.24.155.27, server: "fqdn", request: "GET /page.php HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "127.0.0.1"
```